# Windows Phone 7 XNA Game, MouseMove, OnUpdate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

I am developing a Arkanoid (Breakout) game on Windows Phone 7.

I added a handler to the base of my GamePage constructor:

```
public GamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Get the content manager from the application
        contentManager = (Application.Current as App).Content;

        // Create a timer for this page
        timer = new GameTimer();
        timer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        timer.Update += OnUpdate;
        timer.Draw += OnDraw;

        base.OnMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(GamePage_MouseMove);

        init();
    }
```

And this is the handling function:

```
private void GamePage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //this changes the ball coordinates based on yVel and xVel properties of the ball
        ball.moveBall();
    }
```

The GamePage_MouseMove function is never called and I dont know why. The ball is not moving.

Another issue is the onUpdate function:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the ball rectangle intersects with the paddle rectange, change the ball yVel
        if (ball.BallRec.Intersects(paddle.PaddleRec))
            ball.YVel = -1;
        ball.moveBall();
    }
```

Even if the ball intersects with the paddle it continues to move to the original direction and doesnt "bounce".

Please help.

### Update

After a small modification the onUpdate function is now:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
        if(ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            paddle.movePaddle((int)ms.X);
    }
```

But the paddle is not moving.

Comment: TouchControl should be used, also XNA Framework for wp7 also provides gestures to read inputs. VerticalDrag and horizontalDrag gesture can be used to contol the padel

and the delta value from those gestures can be used to move padel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider inspecting the [MouseState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.aspx) structure during your Update rather than trying to capture mouse events.

Something along the lines of:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  // snip...

  MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

  //Respond to the position of the mouse.
  //For example, change the position of a sprite 
  //based on mouseState.X or mouseState.Y

  //Respond to the left mouse button being pressed
  if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    //The left mouse button is pressed. 
  }

  base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

There is a great example of how to use the mouse as an input device in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197572.aspx

In addition, for the phone, remember that you have true touch capabilities as well as the accelerometer available to you.  You can learn about all the input options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203899.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I updated my question with your example. Please take a look because it doesn't work..

Comment: I fixed the code. I should have used TouchCollection instead of MouseState. cheers